# How to implement this AWS RDS Purchase recommendation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, reserved-instances

I have 2 RDS databases size db.t2.medium. I went to AWS recommendations and got this:
[image: tt]

So far I've done only EC2 reservations. I am not sure how to proceed from here.
**First** I guess I have to make the reservation on RDS menu for 8 db.t2.micro reserved instances...

**And after?**
**How can I modify existing databases to assign them 4 db.t2.micros to each one?**
[image]

- I see where to change the instance type.... but I will be replacing one database db.t2.medium with another one db.t2.micro...
- Maybe storage auto-escaling will do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Reserved Instances are *just a billing construct*, if you have purchased RIs AWS will try to apply the discounts to your running instances at the billing time. I.e. you don’t *assign* RIs to your actual RDS instances, you get the discount automatically.
2. Reserved Instances capacity doesn’t have to match the running instances. The price for `db.t2.medium` is the same as for 2x `db.t2.small` or 4x `db.t2.micro`. So if you purchase 8x `db.t2.micro` RI it will cover your 2x `db.t2.medium`. Instead of *8x micro* you can purchase *2x medium* or *1x large* - from the billing perspective it’s the same.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Note that #2 only applies to instances which offer size flexibility.  It does not apply to MS SQL Server nor to non-BYOL Oracle.